# Implementing min gas fee for pallet_evm

Tags: evm, frontier

I have my base currency as 18 decimals like 1_000_000_000_000_000_000. I want to set my base fee to charge using `1_000_000_000_000_000_000` for each evm transaction. How can i do? currently i have done this but not working properly.

```
pub struct FixedGasPrice;

impl FeeCalculator for FixedGasPrice {
    fn min_gas_price() -> U256 {
        (1 * 1_000_000_000).into()
    }
}
```

if i try to change this formula into `(1 * 1_000_000_000_000_000_000).into()` i am getting error whenever i try to deploy the contract from remix. I am getting below error:

```
creation of MyToken20 errored: [ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{"value":{"code":-32603,"data":{"code":-32603,"message":"submit transaction to pool failed: Pool(InvalidTransaction(InvalidTransaction::Custom(1)))"}}}
```

Comment: Consider specifying: what error are you getting?

Comment: creation of MyToken20 errored: [ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{"value":{"code":-32603,"data":{"code":-32603,"message":"submit transaction to pool failed: Pool(InvalidTransaction(InvalidTransaction::Custom(1)))"}}}'

Comment: hey @FarazAhmad, were you able to change the runtime params as I said in my reply? Please consider accepting it as the correct answer if it worked for you.

Comment: hey @afm i tried using your solution but in my case the transction fee keeps on decreasing ... supoose for 1st traction its 100 milli then for 2 second traction it becomes 100 micro them pico nano and them famto..it keeps on decreasing how can i fix this???

Answer (score 3):

To activate and set the `BaseFee` in your Frontier-based chain, you can simply change [these runtime parameters](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/frontier-node-template/blob/1b6bff4e88e6d0345887c0ecbd63401f9474aa91/runtime/src/lib.rs#L341):

```rust
frame_support::parameter_types! {
    pub IsActive: bool = true;
    pub DefaultBaseFeePerGas: U256 = U256::from(1_000_000_000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its likely web3.js has a great difference on gas_price with your own, you should add `gasPrice` to your transaction's option:

```
   gasPrice: await web3.eth.getGasPrice()
```